# Regex not Capturing Properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

So I have code where I'm trying to split the string into its lowercase letters. I thought I have it correct, but when I run the code, the array has 8 cells that contain "" aka nothing.
So for example if the string is: "I have sweets" I want the array to return: ["h", "a", "v", "e", "s", "w", "e", "e", "t", "s"]

This is my code:

```
let s1 = "Are they here";
let words1 = s1.split(/([a-z])/g);
```

Comment: `split` will split at every appearance the pattern, in this case of a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier just to match each of the lower-case characters:

```js
let s1 = "Are they here";
let words1 = s1.match(/[a-z]/g);
console.log(words1);
```

Comment: Oh hey that works! I didn't even know about match, I appreciate it!